# How to remove code from Try and Catch?

Tags: java, android, json, try-catch

I have strings in my code that are within a try/catch.  I need to access the strings in other parts of the same class but I can not.  I try removing the try/catch and it doesn't let me without throwing the following error:

> Unhandled exception type JSONException

Here is my try / catch code.  What are the best methods for getting this into a normal class so that I can access the strings in other parts of code in the same class? (this code is inside of the default oncreate bundle)

```
      try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
            JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing  JSON item in a String Variable

            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String messages = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGES);
            String wins = c.getString(TAG_WINS);
            String display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String pw = c.getString(TAG_PW);
            String created = c.getString(TAG_CREATED);
            String updated = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED);

            //Importing TextView

            TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfullname);
            TextView messages1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.envelope);
            TextView wins1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wins);
            TextView created1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcreated_at);
            TextView updated1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvupdated_at);

            //Set JSON Data in its respectable TextView

            name1.setText("Hello " + name);

            updated1.setText("Your last login was " + updated);

           // print error if applicable.
         } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make those string global that you want to access.Declare those at class level so that it can be accessed any where with in the class.

For example 
lets say your class name is X and you want to access `String name`
then do like this

```
class X
{
String name;
try
{
name=c.getString(TAG_NAME);
//other codes
}
catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now to answer this  *I need to access the strings in other parts of the same class*

you can access any where with in the class whether in the same method or different method

Comment: I tried this but I still cannot access "messages1" after the catch. I am trying to call the string in a public void View view inside of an "if" statement but when I hover over it, it says "messages1 cannot be resolved to a variable" :( I am going insane here –  user3053446 11 mins ago

Comment: @user3053446 have you dclared messages1 at class level?

Comment: @user3053446 fell free to ask if you have any other queries

Answer (score 0):

Declare your strings outside the try-catch block

and assign them value inside the try block.

Outside try block

```
    String name = null;
    String messages = null;
    String wins = null;
    String display = null;
    String email = null;
    String pw = null;
    String created = null;
    String updated = null;
```

Inside try block

```
// Storing  JSON item in a String Variable

            name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            messages = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGES);
            wins = c.getString(TAG_WINS);
            display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);
            email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            pw = c.getString(TAG_PW);
            created = c.getString(TAG_CREATED);
            updated = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED);
```

Another way If you want to remove try-cath is to add "throws" to your method/class (that5 way you would be propagating the exception to calling-handling class).

By the way, This question only makes sense if you are very new to java, else you ned to brush your basic java school big time :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the strings outside the try and they will have wider scope so that they're available elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is declare these variables outside the `try-catch` may be declare them globally like

```
String name;
            String messages;
            String wins ;
            String display;
            String email;
            String pw;
            String created ;
            String updated ;
try {
            // Getting JSON Array

            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
            JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);






            // Storing  JSON item in a String Variable

            name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            messages = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGES);
            wins = c.getString(TAG_WINS);
            display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);
            email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            pw = c.getString(TAG_PW);
            created = c.getString(TAG_CREATED);
            updated = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED);



            //Importing TextView

            TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfullname);
            TextView messages1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.envelope);
            TextView wins1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wins);
            TextView created1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcreated_at);
            TextView updated1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvupdated_at);




            //Set JSON Data in its respectable TextView

      name1.setText("Hello " + name);





      updated1.setText("Your last login was " + updated);






 // print error if applicable.
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your string variables as globel.

> private static final NAME="name";

use NAME in all the required area

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        String name = null;
        String messages = null;
        String wins = null;
        String display = null;
        String email = null;
        String pw = null;
        String created = null;
        String updated = null;
      try {
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
        JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

        // Storing  JSON item in a String Variable
        name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        messages = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGES);
        wins = c.getString(TAG_WINS);
        display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);
        email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
        pw = c.getString(TAG_PW);
        created = c.getString(TAG_CREATED);
        updated = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED);

        //Importing TextView
        TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfullname);
        TextView messages1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.envelope);
        TextView wins1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wins);
        TextView created1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcreated_at);
        TextView updated1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvupdated_at);

        //Set JSON Data in its respectable TextView
        name1.setText("Hello " + name);
        updated1.setText("Your last login was " + updated);

       // print error if applicable.
      } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but I still cannot access "messages1" after the catch.

I am trying to call the string in a public void View view inside of an "if" statement but when I hover over it, it says "messages1 cannot be resolved to a variable" :(  I am going insane here

Answer (score 0):

I think u can replace getXXX method to optXXX method, it will be a better choice, do you think so ? 
eg:

```
try {
    name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //
}
```

now u can try below code:

```
  name = c.optString(TAG_NAME);
```

OK, that's all.